# Read com ports using threading in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I would like some advise on threading as I'm new to it. I've read several articles on threading online.

I'm reading com ports data. I would like to use threading such that it will read the data every 5 seconds and update the data on the listbox. Currently, all the data is being read.
I'm unsure where to start.

Where shall i start putting my thread codes? I'm using Windows Form,c# VS2008.

Here's my codes to read the data from com ports:

```
    void datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {            
        myDelegate d = new myDelegate(update);
        listBox1.Invoke(d, new object[] { });

    }


    public void update()
    {           

        while (serialPortN.BytesToRead > 0)
            bBuffer.Add((byte)serialPortN.ReadByte());
        ProcessBuffer(bBuffer);

    }

    private void ProcessBuffer(List<byte> bBuffer)
    {            

        int numberOfBytesToRead = 125;

        if (bBuffer.Count >= numberOfBytesToRead)
        {            


                listBox1.Items.Add("SP: " + (bBuffer[43].ToString()) + "  " + " HR: " + (bBuffer[103].ToString()));


            // Remove the bytes read from the list
            bBuffer.RemoveRange(0, numberOfBytesToRead);

        }

    }
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a timer? Put it into the InitializeComponent method of the form that is appropriate,

```
using System.Timers;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.Text = "Form1";

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);

    //timer.Enabled = true; // you may need this, but probably not if you are calling the start method.
    timer.Start();
}

void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // put your code here to read the COM port
}
```

The only other problem with this code is that you will get an exception Cross-thread operation not valid.

You will have to modify your code like this,

```
private void ProcessBuffer(List<byte> bBuffer)
{
    int numberOfBytesToRead = 125;

    if (bBuffer.Count >= numberOfBytesToRead)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("SP: " + (bBuffer[43].ToString()) + "  " + " HR: " + (bBuffer[103].ToString()));
        });

        // Remove the bytes read from the list
        bBuffer.RemoveRange(0, numberOfBytesToRead);
    }
}
```

The reason is that the ProcessBuffer method will be running on a background thread. Background threads cannot access UI components on the UI thread. So you have to call this.Invoke which will run that update to the listbox on the UI thread.

Have a look here if you want to know more about the Invoke method,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

UPDATE:

So within the TimerElapsed method you will want to call your code, but it is not clear to me which part of your code it should call? What is the 'datareceived' method for, there is nothing calling it in your code snippet.

So I am guessing it will be this,

```
void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Update();
}

public void Update()
{
    while (serialPortN.BytesToRead > 0)
        buffer.Add((byte)serialPortN.ReadByte());
    ProcessBuffer(buffer);
}
```

It doesn't make sense for it to be calling the ProcessBuffer method because where will the buffer come from?

If I am not on the right track perhaps expand your code sample, and I am happy to help more.

Please note a few style changes I made to your code (feel free to take them or leave them), a method in C# should start with a capital letter, and calling the variable bBuffer is not standard in C#. Another point if that method is only called from within the class it should be made private.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your reply. For the read com port data, I've insert the data under a button click event. Should I put the button click event handler under the void timer elapsed? Thanks !

Comment: I am not 100% following. What do you mean you have inserted the data under a button click event? Inserted what data? If you want to know if you can put the button click event handler after the void TimerElapsed in the code file, then yes you can.

Comment: Sorry Peter, What i meant is that in the timer elapsed method can I insert the process buffer coding? Since the process buffer method that processes the data.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to call the 'update' method from within the 'TimerElapsed' method? It depends where the bBuffer comes from? It is not clear to me exactly what you are wanting to do every 5 seconds, read from the port, or update the GUI. I will update the answer above.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for you reply. I would like to read the com port every 5s. I've tried calling the update() method but the listbox kept reading the com port. It doesn't read every 5s. Currently, I'm using your codes. But the timer is not ticking every 5s.. Thanks once again.

Comment: The only different is that I place my Timer codes here:                           public ReadData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();          
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Start();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
           
        }

Comment: The datareceived method is called on the button connect click: Here's the code. serialPortN.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceived);

Comment: Are you still trying to resolve this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx shows how to use a timer. Perhaps you have to set the elapsed event before calling the start method. I have updated the answer.