# C# and serial communication how to flush the device to read same data again?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, reset, flush

Okay so I am stuck for almost **20 days** now in the same problem of a serial communication device. I have a hardware sensor which read tags and returns the tag code number on every read through serial com port 1 or 3.Any of these I use doesn't matter. I am using a program I wrote in c# to play with the incoming data.
Now problem is that if forexample:
my sensor reads tag with code **"e2 0 10 1 83 10 1 23 7 0 d0 c0 1 be"**
It will not read this tag again unless I switch of the sensor and turn it on again (Power reset) . So I can't figure out how to make my **sensor forget all the data it read till I closed the port**. **ANY ONE CAN HELP PLEASE I AM DESPERATE NOW**
Some one told me that we need to write to device with some commands but he didn't know more than that.
Here is the current code:

```
 void IntializeSensor()
    {
        try
        {
            if (mySerialPort==null)
            {
                mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

                mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;

                mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
                mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
                mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                LoglistBox.Items.Add("--Port Intilalized at COM1--");
                mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
  void OpenPort()
    {
        try
        {
            str = "";

            if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                ClosePort();
                Thread.Sleep(6000);

            }
            mySerialPort.Open();

            LoglistBox.Items.Add("--Port Opened at COM1 Success--");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            LoglistBox.Items.Add("--Port Opened Failed--Error: "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

void ClosePort()
        {

```
        try
        {
            mySerialPort.Write("ABCABCABCABCABC");
            mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            mySerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            mySerialPort.Dispose();
            mySerialPort.Close();

            LoglistBox.Items.Add("--Port Closed at COM1 Success--");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            LoglistBox.Items.Add("--Port Closed Failed--Error: " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

private  void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        try
        {

            if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars) return; 
            SerialPort COMPort = (SerialPort)sender;

            int bytes = COMPort.BytesToRead;

            //create a byte array to hold the awaiting data

            byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];

            //read the data and store it

            COMPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);



            // System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

            str = ByteArrayToHexString(comBuffer);

            holdfirstvalue += str;
            //str = str +" "+ str;
            //MessageBox.Show("after concat "+str);


            if (str.Contains("FF") || str.Contains("F F") || str.Contains("F"))
            {


             SetText(holdfirstvalue.ToString());// ONE TAG CODE SENT TO BE SET IN LIST
                str = "";
                holdfirstvalue = "";
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // LoglistBox.Items.Add("--Port Opened Failed--Error: " + ex.InnerException);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+" "+ex.InnerException);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that jumps out at me other than you subscribing to the DataReceived event. I've had nothing but problems with this in the past. Basically when I read from a serialport, I have a thread which just _serialPort.ReadByte() and handle it like that. I dunno if that will help you but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Are you saying that you can never read that exact string again, even if you scan it a second time?  Or that you can't see the data more than once for a given scan?

Comment: Can you give us specific details on the hardware sensor? If you move the tag away from the sensor and move a different tag into range does it transmit the tag code?

Comment: Hi Jeff,The sensor is a simple RF based tag reader, if I move a tag infront of it , it returns a code, then if I move another tag infront of it, it also returns the code. But if I move the 1st tag again it does not read it unless I give sensor a power reset.

Comment: Hi Bobson, I cannot read the same data twice . Unless I give sensor a power reset.

Comment: Hi gleng, I dont know any other way of doing it. Can you past some code here to tell me any other way to deal with serial communication. I googled but everywhere people use DataReceived Event.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a problem with the reader, rather than the code...  Do you have any way to test that the reader is working correctly?  For example, the barcode scanners I use can enter their data directly into a text editor.  Do you have the software that came with your reader?

Comment: @Bobson yes the reader is fine , I mean it came with a small UI which runs on windows. So on that UI we have Open/ Close port, Reset Head, Read Tag buttons. If I press Reset head, then reader resets and can read same tag again. But I don't know what code runs behind it.

Comment: Interesting.  If you hit Read Tag it won't read the same tag a second time until you reset it?  What's the brand/model for the tag reader? Sounds like there's a specific command you need to send to it, and the documentation may say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the code in hex which actually resets the sensor.
So to help anyone out there who bought Middle Range UHF RFID Reader or any type of this model.

What we did is we hacked into the wires of serial port by soldering copper wire on data pins. Then we attached the other end of those copper wires to my laptop and used the terminal reader "Putty" to see what is actually being sent by the PC to the Reader on RESET HEAD button click.

This way we found the hex code , converted it to byte array and here is the C# code to write it to reader device by serial port and resets the device:

```
{ 
mySerialPort.Open();
        byte[] bytesToSend = StringToByteArray("A00265F9");// correct command to reset READER
        mySerialPort.Write(bytesToSend, 0, 4);
}
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                             .ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your comments, even the program that is shipped with it does not read the same bar-code twice in a row. Am I right?

To me it seems that "the tag reader manufacturer" may have put that mechanism intentionally to prevent user mistakenly scan an item twice at check-out. because it happens a lot that a same stays on the scanner or be crossed against the scanner couple of times when moving things around.

Unless you have access to the scanner Firmware and are able to make changes yourself, I'd say contact the manufacturer. I would contact the manufacturer and ask about this directly. There should be a command that tells the scanner to "Get out of lock mode and restart scanning again" for the special case of scanning a same item several times (e.g. buying multiple similar things.)

They should provide you with a manual with the list of all the commands you can send to your device and you use this commands to build up your system.

One more thing to try! can you scope out your serial port using "Real Term" or any other terminal monitoring application to see if the scanner sends the code to the PC after you scan the same item again or not? This helps you to isolate the problem to make sure if it is the Scanner Firmware or the desktop software. (it seems to me that it is the scanner Firmware ignoring the item because you say it works fine when you reset it)

edit: also I see you are reading your serial port based on DataREadyEvent, again, if it was me, I would add another thread with a very short delay say 20ms or 50ms to keep reading the serial port constantly. there are plenty of examples on how to implement this on the net, one simple and quick way of this is described here:

[Read com ports using threading in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570379/read-com-ports-using-threading-in-c-sharp)

Hope it helps.